# How to use sed to enter content after specific content?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I currently can use **sed** to do a replace like this:

```
sed -i 's/find/replace/g' /file
```

Is is possible to find content such as `http {` and insert the following after it with **sed**?

`\t/server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;` (tab before the content)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done with `\a`:

```
$ sed '/^http {/ a\\tserver_names_hash_bucket_size 64;' file
```

It will look for the lines starting with `http {` (`^` stands for beginning of line) and will add (`\a`) the text you indicate.